# Unable to find new release ( after interuppting a release upgrade)

Tags: upgrade, release-management

i am on 12.10 and had to interrupt  a 'do-release-upgrade'  to 13.10

Now, later, when i run 'do-release-upgrade;, it reports back as 'unable to find new release'

Can someone help out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
you may need to use the debian menthod:
`sudo sed -i 's/quantal/raring/' /etc/apt/sources.list` then run the above command
then to upgrade then you can upgrade to saucy by running `sudo sed -i 's/raring/saucy/' /etc/apt/sources.list` then run the 1st command

if you meant 13.04 and not 13.10 don't do the second sed command

Comment: sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade <---- This worked ! And yes, i meant 13.04 ( not 13.10 ) -- Thanks much!